# Add notes to books in Calibre

Tags: notes, ebooks, calibre

Does anyone know of a plugin that lets you add notes to books in [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/)?

I read quite a lot of books (actual books) and I'm quite used to add little side notes on small sticky notes. Since some books aren't shipped to my location I decided to buy the e-books and use Calibre to read them. Only thing I missed was a way to add notes. I've been using Mendeley for quite some time now, so I know it's possible to add notes but I'm using Mendeley for my work and I don't want to clutter it with e-books. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I read somewhere that there is a recipie reader program that also allows you to make notes.  The catch is that apparently you need to be pretty versatile with html markup

Comment: Yeah, I saw that....although I'm quite adapt with html I don't really want to go and dive into html codes every time I want to add a side note. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm not so adept, so I understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* an answer but you'll have to decide whether making your own annotations is more imporpant than GUI consistency: https://okular.kde.org/ (Obviously a KDE program, so it will install lots of dependency libraries and look ugly in a gnome environment, but it *does* what you need...)

Actually *making your own annotations in Calibre?*

#### No-go...

Comment: In het land van de blinden...  etc. :(

Comment: yeah, I know okular from when I used KDE. I just thought that since calibre can import notes made with other programs I could also add notes.....Helaas pindakaas.